# CasperJSでstepのタイムアウト時に、エラーで終了させず、次にステップに継続する方法

Tags: javascript, casperjs

CasperJSでstepのタイムアウト時に、エラーで終了させず、次のステップに継続させる方法を教えて下さい。

下記のコードでは、

```
casper.on('step.timeout', function(step, timeout) {
  this.echo(step);
  this.clear();
  this.page.stop();
});
```

下記のエラーが発生し、スクリプト自体が終了してしまいます。

```
313
[error] [phantom] Maximum step execution timeout exceeded for step 313
Maximum step execution timeout exceeded for step 313
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようにoptionのonStepTimeoutを設定することでうまくいきました。

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  stepTimeout: 10000,
  onStepTimeout: function(millionseconds, step) {
    this.echo('stepped step is ' + step);
    this.clear();
  }
});
```

this.page.stop();を加えるとうまくいかなかったです。

Comment: 解決済みであることが他の方にわかりやすいように、承認をお願いできませんか？（このコメントは後で削除します

Comment: @unarist 　承認致しました。